# Array.splice() shows too much

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-splice

I have problem with splice. I have code

```
const findMissingLetter=(array)=>{
  let result,alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  if(array[0]===array[0].toUpperCase()) alphabet = alphabet.toUpperCase();
  let start = alphabet.split('').indexOf(array[0]);
  return alphabet.split('').splice(start,start+array.length+1);
}
```

This function should find missing letter in alphabet and return this

The argument contains only lower case letters or upper case letters.
The problem in this code is, that if i use it on arguments :

`['a','b','c','d','f']` - then it is working well, returning `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']`

but if i have uppercase letters :
`['O','Q','R','S']` - then it returns `['O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']`.

```js
const findMissingLetter = (array) => {
  let result, alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  if (array[0] === array[0].toUpperCase()) alphabet = alphabet.toUpperCase();
  let start = alphabet.split('').indexOf(array[0]);
  return alphabet.split('').splice(start, start + array.length + 1);
}

console.log(findMissingLetter(['a','b','c','d','f']));
console.log(findMissingLetter(['O','Q','R','S']));
```

Where might be the problem?

Comment: ['a','b','c','d','f'] - then it is working well, returning ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']?You are finding the missing word so I think the result should be "e". Is that right ?

Answer (score 0):

You need only `array.length + 1` without the start index, because this is the wanted length of the result array.

```js
const findMissingLetter = array => {
    let alphabet = Array.from("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");

    if (array[0] === array[0].toUpperCase()) alphabet = alphabet.map(c => c.toUpperCase());

    let start = alphabet.indexOf(array[0]);

    return alphabet.splice(start, array.length + 1);
}

console.log(...findMissingLetter(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f'])); // ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
console.log(...findMissingLetter(['O', 'Q', 'R', 'S'])); // ['O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S']
```

Comment: Oh, seriously, now everything is fine :D Thanks so much

Comment: Should it not return e and P ?